# Is there a reading order for Grimm Fairy Tales - Age of Darkness?

Tags: comics, suggested-order, grimm-fairy-tales

I've searched the net but I can't find the order for this one. It seems like a crossover but maybe it isn't.

Can someone tell me the right order to read these?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Age of Darkness is a way to tell readers which titles connect, in one way or another, to the universe altering events of Grimm Fairy Tales #100 and the subsequent twelve-issue GFT Realm War “Age of Darkness” series that is set to release right after 100.

The reading order of essential Age of Darkness issues is as follows:

```
Grimm Fairy Tales 2014 Annual 
Grimm Fairy Tales Realm Knights Age of Darkness one-shot 
Grimm Fairy Tales 2014 Giant Sized Edition 
Grimm Fairy Tales #99
Grimm Fairy Tales #100 
GFT Realm War “Age of Darkness” #1
```

[Source](http://blog.zenescope.com/2014/05/grimm-fairy-tales-100-and-realm-war-age-of-darkness-announcement/)

For more about theses titles and a complete titles list check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm_Fairy_Tales_%28comics%29)

Comment: what about the other bits? there's a lot of tie-ins. where do they fit? thanks again :)

Comment: You could follow the [release schedule](http://graphicpolicy.com/2014/03/18/zenescopes-age-of-darkness-official-release-schedule/)

Comment: http://blog.zenescope.com/2014/05/grimm-fairy-tales-100-and-realm-war-age-of-darkness-announcement/